# I am recieving logs which is in below format, I need to convert this to python dictionary to extract the data, getting JSONDecodeError

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

This is my code

```
import json
data = '{"action_name": None, "execution_time": "00:00:00.000915", "timestamp": "2020-06-09T03:42:21.299294Z", "ip_address": None, "request": OrderedDict([("method", "GET"), ("full_path", "ggggg"), ("data", None), ("query_params", "{}")]), "response": OrderedDict([("status_code", 404), ("data", None)]), "user": OrderedDict([("id", None), ("username", None)])}'
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

The error is 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 17 (char 16)

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 17 (char 16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data string, there is a python dictionary that in a sting representation  and not a JSON format.
to convert the data to a dictionary you just need to use `eval()` and to import OrderedDict since you have it in the dictionary like

```
from collections import OrderedDict    

json_data = eval(data)
```

That will convert the data string to a dictionary as

```
{'action_name': None,
 'execution_time': '00:00:00.000915',
 'timestamp': '2020-06-09T03:42:21.299294Z',
 'ip_address': None,
 'request': OrderedDict([('method', 'GET'),
              ('full_path', 'ggggg'),
              ('data', None),
              ('query_params', '{}')]),
 'response': OrderedDict([('status_code', 404), ('data', None)]),
 'user': OrderedDict([('id', None), ('username', None)])}
```

Comment: This is clearly the right answer. But you may want to warn about the dangers of `eval`. If the data is untrusted, `eval`ing it can do bad things to your system.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, json [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html).

```
import json

data = '{"action_name": None, "execution_time": "00:00:00.000915", "timestamp": "2020-06-09T03:42:21.299294Z", "ip_address": None, "request": OrderedDict([("method", "GET"), ("full_path", "ggggg"), ("data", None), ("query_params", "{}")]), "response": OrderedDict([("status_code", 404), ("data", None)]), "user": OrderedDict([("id", None), ("username", None)])}'
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: yes, but i need to get the data in the key: value pair example: 
dict["execution_time"]  = "00:00:00.000915"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, posting for reference

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
data = '{"action_name": None, "execution_time": "00:00:00.000915", "timestamp": "2020-06-09T03:42:21.299294Z", "ip_address": None, "request": OrderedDict([("method", "GET"), ("full_path", "ggggg"), ("data", None), ("query_params", "{}")]), "response": OrderedDict([("status_code", 404), ("data", None)]), "user": OrderedDict([("id", None), ("username", None)])}'
json_data = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
dict_json = eval(json.loads(json_data))
print(dict_json['request'])
```

Comment: The round-trip through `json` doesn't achieve anything useful here. Only the `eval` that you do at the end converts the initial string into a dictionary. You could do that directly, without messing around with `json` first.